# Add or Remove tabs dynamically using ui tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a functionality in which i need to create tabs dynamically when i click on any menu. Content related to that menus should be open in new tab.

I am trying this code to add new tab

```
$("#tabs").children('ul').append('<li><a href="#' + attrHref + '" >' + attrHref + '</a>         
 <span href="javascript:void(o);" style="cursor:pointer;" id="removeTab"><img height="17"     
  style="margin-right:4px;margin-left:-12px" src="./Content/Images/delete_icon.png" />
  </span>');
    $("#tabs").append('<div id="' + attrHref + '">' + attrHref + ' Content</div>');
    $("#tabs").tabs('refresh');
```

For removing a tab i used following code:

```
    $(document).on("click", "#removeTab", function (e) {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('aria-controls');
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $("#" + id).remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('refresh');
});
```

It Works fine for chrome and firefox but produces error in IE.

Comment: Maybe you could hide and show it...

Comment: I am trying to add new tabs and remove tabs according to my requirements dynamically. Code that I have written is working fine for chrome but producing error in Firefox.  @tilwin joy

Comment: This looks ok, Can you provide a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net) so that we can debug it..?